# php laravel: response 200 produces 500 error every so often

Tags: php, laravel

Even though I return 200 I get a 500 response about every 50th request:

```
public function ping()
{
    $user = DB::select(DB::raw("select top 1 * from [users] where [users].[id] = 1;"));
    // die(var_dump($user));

   return response('Success', 200);
}
```

Uncommenting `die()` eliminates the problem. So I think laravels response function might be causing the problem.

Comment: Can you please add the stack trace when it returns 500 error.

Comment: You can see the last errors in `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: The error 500 is the general error that php throws when there has occurred a fatal error in your code. Search your logs for a fatal error to find out what is causing it. Besides that, laravel response function will always send the response you define in the parameters